# Сменить MAC адрес на роутере ASUS

Tags: роутер, asus

Есть новый роутер ASUS RT-N11P, решил заменить им старый TP-Link. Начал подключать через админку без кабеля. В итоге интернет не работает. Ошибка в админке: `Служба DHCP поставщика услуг Интернета работает неправильно`. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Насколько я понял, что мне надо сменить MAC адрес нового роутера на MAC адрес старого. В разделе `Интернет` админки я прописал MAC адрес старого роутера и сохранил. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но ничего не изменилось и даже в главном меню админки также отображается MAC адрес нового роутера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким? Как поменять MAC адрес на роутере ASUS?

Comment: вы кнопку _Применить_ то точно нажали? :)

Comment: @teran конечно, MAC адрес сохранился, но в главном меню все равно показывает не тот MAC.

Comment: на последнем скрине скорее всего адреса для внутренней сети. а наружу торчит тот, что на втором.

Comment: @teran Эти адреса ведь тоже должны поменяться, нет?

Comment: нет, провайдеру важно только то что наружу смотрит.